# Как установить librosa?

Tags: python, аудио

во время установки librosa ругается на  llvmlite, попытался установить его отдельно - та же самая ошибка

```
pip install librosa




  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for llvmlite ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-3EMUql/llvmlite/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp0NQ_FVpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  /usr/bin/python /tmp/pip-build-3EMUql/llvmlite/ffi/build.py
    File "/tmp/pip-build-3EMUql/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 122
      raise ValueError(msg.format(_ver_check_skip)) from e
                                                       ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  error: command '/usr/bin/python' failed with exit status 1
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for llvmlite
  Running setup.py clean for llvmlite
Successfully built librosa audioread resampy
Failed to build llvmlite
Installing collected packages: audioread, decorator, joblib, numpy, setuptools, llvmlite, funcsigs, six, singledispatch, enum34, numba, scipy, resampy, scikit-learn, pycparser, cffi, soundfile, librosa
  Running setup.py install for llvmlite ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-3EMUql/llvmlite/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-yFJ6w6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    running install
    running build
    got version from file /tmp/pip-build-3EMUql/llvmlite/llvmlite/_version.py {'version': '0.32.1', 'full': 'aa11b129c0b55973067422397821ae6d44fa5e70'}
    running build_ext
    /usr/bin/python /tmp/pip-build-3EMUql/llvmlite/ffi/build.py
      File "/tmp/pip-build-3EMUql/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 122
        raise ValueError(msg.format(_ver_check_skip)) from e
                                                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    error: command '/usr/bin/python' failed with exit status 1
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-3EMUql/llvmlite/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-yFJ6w6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-3EMUql/llvmlite/
```

Стоит ubuntu 18.04, python 3.6.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась установкой анаконды и последующей установкой на нее librosa

```
conda install -c conda-forge librosa
```

Comment: Да, всякие там llvm (на который эта либа завязана) через pip плохо ставятся, лучше через анаконду обычно, да.